# performSegue with programmatically added Navigation button

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, rightbarbuttonitem

I am trying to customize a Navigation bar button item programmatically... I am just having some issues here which I am sure is an easy fix. I want to make it the default Add button for now, but also in the future will want to make the bar button item a custom icon I create. so I guess I would like to know both ways how to programmatically change a navigation bar button to default styles and custom icons...thanks!

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let rightbutton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "uploadButtonClicked")

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbutton


}
```

Comment: do this in `viewDidLoad` method and also don't forget to call `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would do it with the default add button:

```
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: "uploadButtonClicked")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

Here is how you would programmatically add a custom image:

```
    let customImage = UIImage(named: "customButtonImage")
    let customButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: customImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "uploadButtonClicked:")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customButton
```

To perform the segue, you can do this:

```
@IBAction func uploadButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Or, if you want to go to another storyboard from there, then your IBAction will look like this:

```
@IBAction func uploadButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let nc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
    let vc = nc.viewControllers.first as! YourViewController
```